# differences-in-differences regression with peer effects

Tags: regression

I am interested in running a differences-in-differences regression that exploits the passage of a law at the state-level. I am also interested in understanding not only what happens to the treated units in those states, but also to peers of those units in other states. For instance, if the units are families, and a law is passed in California, I would like to study the effect of these laws on families outside California that are linked to families in California (such as having a family tie or a social tie). Therefore, the treatment group are not the treated families, but rather their peers.

If someone knows of useful literature on something along these lines, I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie but off the top off my head - no literature.

Peer State would be another level of treatment, socially tied individuals would need a new variable identifying them as a cluster.  Use cluster as random effect.